# Express: return is not showing array in api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

So I have collections of Teacher, Classes. to understand my problem its necessary to understand my database. the structure is

```
const TeacherSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: "teacher"
    },
    userid: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    
    profileImage: { 
      type: String, 
      required: false
    },
    classes: [{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'class'
    }]//1 teacher will have multiple classes
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

and the class:

```
const ClassSchema = new Schema(
  {
    subject: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    teacher:[{
      type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'teacher'
    }],//once class will have only one teacher

  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

What i want to do is, I want to show teacher how many classes he/she has. here is my controller.

```
exports.getAllClass= async (req, res, next) => {
    let teacherClasses
    try{
      teacherClasses= await Teacher.findById(req.params.id)//teacher database
      arrayOfClass= teacherClasses.classes //getting the class it has array of objectID
      arrayOfClass.forEach(async (classes)=>{
        let classDB =await Class.findById(classes)
        console.log(classDB.subject)// in the console it shows all the classes.
        return res.status(200).json({
          'name':classDB.subject //but here it only shows one class,the first class name
        })

        


      });
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

I have tried many thing, but cant reach to a proper solution. Can you tell me what did i do wrong here or is there any better approach? I want to show all the classes in the return. I am new in programming hence assigned in complex task, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `forEach` on the `arrayOfClass` and within that `forEach` you return and send the response. So as soon as the first promise is resolved, the response is sent.

One simple way to do this is to use a `for .. of` loop and await each `class`-promise inside and keep track of each result. Once that's done you can send the response:

```
...
const classes = [];

for(const classId of arrayofClass) {
   const classDB = await Class.findById(classId);
   classes.push({ name: classDB.subject });
}

return res.json(classes);
```

Another way to do this is to use `Promise.all()` which might be better if you're dealing with a bigger dataset as is processes in parallel whereas the first solution processes in sequence:

```
...
const classPromises = await Promise.all(arrayofClass.map(classId => Class.findById(classId)));
const result = classPromises.map(classDB => ({
            name: classDB.subject
        }));

return res.json(result);
```